# How to compare ImplicitRegion with empty region?

Tags: regions, implicit

I have the following function using `ImplicitRegion`:

```
Region222[a_] := 
 ImplicitRegion[
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - a^2] >= 9, {{x, a, a + 2}, {y, a, a + 1}}]
Region222Reduced[a_] :=
 MapAt[Reduce, Region222[a], 1]
Function12[a_] := If[Region222Reduced[a] == EmptyRegion[2], 0, 222]
```

`Function12` should compare `ImplicitRegion` with the empty region and return 0 if they coincide and 222 if they don't coincide. But it does not work properly for the case when the region does not coincide with EmptyRegion[2].

Could you please tell me what I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use one of the following predicates instead:

```
predicate1[region_] := RegionDimension[region]<0
predicate2[region_] := RegionMeasure[region] == 0
```

One of your empty regions:

```
region = Region222[3]
predicate1[region]
predicate2[region]
```

> ImplicitRegion[
>    Sqrt[-9 + x^2 + y^2] >= 9 && 3 <= x <= 5 && 3 <= y <= 4, {x, y}]
>
> True
>
> True

And a non-empty region:

```
region = Region222[10]
predicate1[region]
predicate2[region]
```

> ImplicitRegion[
>    Sqrt[-100 + x^2 + y^2] >= 9 && 10 <= x <= 12 && 10 <= y <= 11, {x, y}]
>
> False
>
> False

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RegionEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionEqual.html) for this.

```
RegionEqual[Region222[3], EmptyRegion[2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
RegionEqual[Region222[10], EmptyRegion[2]]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

```
RegionEqual[Region222[a], EmptyRegion[2]]
```

> ```
> -9 < a <= -5 || 0 <= a < -3 + Sqrt[85]
> ```

Comment: `RegionEqual` doesn't work so well for inexact regions, as in the OP's previous queston.

Comment: I think this is a common problem with a lot of the region functions. `In[24]:= 
predicate3[region_] := RegionEqual[region, EmptyRegion[2]]

In[25]:= Through[{predicate1, predicate2, predicate3}[
    Region222[#[-3 + Sqrt[85]]]]] & /@ {Identity, N}

Out[25]= {{False, False, False}, {True, True, True}}`